# How to add "extra information" at magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, field

I wanna know how to add "extra info" at checkout, this mean, for example, a textfield wen the customer can add "go to the green house". I currently have the Firecheckout and they display a custom field but i can't see into the admin area.

Thanks.

Magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I found answere by myself.

If you have a firecheckout, go to Swissup > Checkout > Checkout Fields and configure custom fields on it.